# ReactJS - Dynamic Component Name with closing tag and children elements

Tags: reactjs

New to React and I try to figure out if it's possible to have a dynamic element name with child components.

What I try to accomplish, is to create a site, that comes with connected/unconnected user area, using the same content with few differences when the user is connected.

To achieve that, I did to layout components like this:

```
//...
export default function PublicLayout(props) {
    return <>
        <Header />
        <HeaderMobile />

        {props.children}

        <Footer />
    </>;
}
```

```
import HeaderPrivate from "../app/components/partials/header-private";

export default function PrivateLayout(props) {
    return <>
        <HeaderPrivate />

        {props.children}
    </>;
}
```

So far I use the `PublicLayout` in my project like that:

```
export default function Home() {
    return <PublicLayout>
        {/*here are my child components*/}
    </PublicLayout>;
}
```

But I want to know if it's possible to have something like this:

```
export default function Home() {
    let connected = false;
    let Layout = connected ? 'PublicLayout' : 'PrivateLayout';

    return <Layout>
        {/*here are my child components*/}
    </Layout>;
}
```

I've seen several solutions for dynamic component names *(all I've seen was for single components without children)*, but none of them worked for me.

I know that there's the other way around to accomplish my goal by doing the following, but if I could I have a dynamic component name it could be the best case for me.

This is the way to do it using an if statement:

```
export default function Home() {
    let connected = false;

    if ( connected ) {
        return <PrivateLayout>
            {/*here are my child components*/}
        </PrivateLayout>;
    }

    return <PublicLayout>
        {/*here are my child components*/}
    </PublicLayout>;
}
```

So, is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely there is a way to dynamically set the component at runtime.

[Choosing the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

Create a component map object to hold references to the imported components

```
const components = {
  PrivateLayout,
  PublicLayout
};
```

And then do something similar to what you tried by using the `connected` value to look up in the map the component to assign to the wrapper.

```
export default function Home() {
  const connected = false;
  const Layout = connected ? components.PublicLayout : components.PrivateLayout;

  return (
    <Layout>
      {/*here are my child components*/}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern (except using [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)) is to [map the name to its component via object](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime):

```
import { PublicLayout, PrivateLayout } from "@layouts";

const LAYOUTS = {
  PublicLayout,
  PrivateLayout,
};

// layoutName = connected ? 'PublicLayout' : 'PrivateLayout'
export default function Home({ layoutName }) {
  const Layout = LAYOUTS[layoutName];

  return <Layout>{...}</Layout>;
}
```